# trimming strings with actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I'm trying to trim white spaces from front and end of a string. Looks like as3 does not have a trim function. Anyone aware of how it can be done?

Comment: Curiously, I got to this page while googling ;)

Comment: I'm not a fan of this whole 'just google it' attitude that is happening more and more on SO. Trawling through random blogs for snippets of information is not the same as getting the collective help from a programming resource such as SO - SO is designed so great answers float to the top based on the opinions of the many, not just one blogger.

Comment: @Chris and Hendy, I also got here from Google.

Answer (score 24):

You have a method that's called trim in the utility class called StringUtil => http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/StringUtil.html#trim%28%29

Answer (score 6):

```
str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you check Adobe's Documentation ?
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class StringExample extends Sprite {
    public function StringExample() {
        var companyStr:String = new String("     Company X");
        var productStr:String = "Product Z Basic     ";
        var emptyStr:String = " ";
        var strHelper:StringHelper = new StringHelper();

        var companyProductStr:String = companyStr + emptyStr + productStr;
        trace("'" + companyProductStr + "'");    // '     Company X Product Z Basic     '

        companyProductStr = strHelper.replace(companyProductStr, "Basic", "Professional");
        trace("'" + companyProductStr + "'");    // '     Company X Product Z Professional     '

        companyProductStr = strHelper.trim(companyProductStr, emptyStr);
        trace("'" + companyProductStr + "'");    // 'Company X Product Z Professional'
    }
}
```

}

class StringHelper {

```
public function StringHelper() {
}

public function replace(str:String, oldSubStr:String, newSubStr:String):String {
    return str.split(oldSubStr).join(newSubStr);
}

public function trim(str:String, char:String):String {
    return trimBack(trimFront(str, char), char);
}

public function trimFront(str:String, char:String):String {
    char = stringToCharacter(char);
    if (str.charAt(0) == char) {
        str = trimFront(str.substring(1), char);
    }
    return str;
}

public function trimBack(str:String, char:String):String {
    char = stringToCharacter(char);
    if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) == char) {
        str = trimBack(str.substring(0, str.length - 1), char);
    }
    return str;
}

public function stringToCharacter(str:String):String {
    if (str.length == 1) {
        return str;
    }
    return str.slice(0, 1);
}
```

}

UPDATE : Oh just saw ItzWarty . -.-

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://jeffchannell.com/ActionScript-3/as3-trim.html

```
function trim( s:String ):String
{
  return s.replace( /^([\s|\t|\n]+)?(.*)([\s|\t|\n]+)?$/gm, "$2" );
}
```

http://www.designscripting.com/2008/11/string-utils-in-as3/ has a ton of string utility functions, including string trim

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
str = StringUtil.trim(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use regex, something like:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /(\t|\n|\s{2,})/g;  
trimmedString = untrimmedString.replace(pattern, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

ItzWarty's solution does not remove trailing spaces.

Amargosh's solution does work perfectly for me, and is also given at http://jeffchannell.com/ActionScript-3/as3-trim.html.

Unfortunatly I don't have enough reputation to vote up Amargosh's solution.

Additionally I had to remove doublequotes so here's my trim:

```
function trim( s:String ):String
{
  return s.replace(/^[\s|"]+|[\s|"]+$/gs, '');
}
```